# I just want list my *.lua file and luac it to *.ttt

Tags: list, sed, sh, luac

I just want list my *.lua file and luac it to *.ttt

my buildData.sh like this

```
findLua()
{

for file in $(find $PWD -name "*.lua")
do
    local dirname=$(dirname "$file")
    local filename=$(basename "$file")
    local fuName=$dirname"/"${filename%.*}

    local outPath = $fuName | sed "s/.*Lua\/\(.*\)/\1/"
    echo $fuName | sed "s/.*Lua\/\(.*\)/\1/"  #echo the absolute path is right
    echo $outPath #the echo nothing why?
    $LUACTOOL -o $TEMPDIR$outPath.ttt $file
    echo out$TEMPDIR$outPath.ttt
done
}
```

this line:

```
 local outPath = $fuName | sed "s/.*Lua\/\(.*\)/\1/"
```

got **null** but I echo  **$fuName | sed "s/.*Lua/(.*)/\1/"** the print is right
why this?anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted to store the output of a command into a variable.  Use the [correct syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution):

```
local outPath=$( echo $fuName | sed "s/.*Lua\/\(.*\)/\1/" )
```